# convert python programme to windows executable

Tags: python, windows-7, py2exe

i m trying to create windows executable from python program which has GUI .
i m using following script

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['gui.py'])
```

it gives following error

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 267
    warnings.warn(msg)
UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'console'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\my python\py2exe.py", line 3, in <module>
    import py2exe
  File "E:\my python\py2exe.py", line 5, in <module>
    setup(console=['ASUP_finalDone1.py'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 140, in setup
    raise SystemExit, gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg
SystemExit: usage: py2exe.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: py2exe.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: py2exe.py --help-commands
   or: py2exe.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

i can't understand why to need for supplying command as it is GUI based application but it worked fine first time and then it gives above error.
please help..........

Comment: How are you invoking this script?

Comment: i m compiling this script from python  IDLE GUI shell.... so then it creates a executable , but it run for first time but not anymore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are compiling this script from the Python IDLE. This is not how it is done with `py2exe`. If you have used `Disutils` before, you might have seen this:

`python setup.py install`.

And same is the case of `py2exe`, you run it from the command line and not the IDLE. So open up `cmd` and then issue the command:

`python setup.py py2exe`

Here `setup.py` is your script file.

This is better explained in the [tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial).

Comment: when i run python setup.py py2exe in cmd it gives python is not recognized command.......

Comment: so try full path like: c:\Python27\python.exe d:\project\myproject\main_script.py py2exe

Comment: This worked. Great. I have a very simple python script about 40 lines, and it generated two folders, `build` and `dist`, total over 300 files and 10MB..... Do I need all these just to run it the little program?